# A question on $S_{6}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This is a part of a proof that there is no simple group of order $120 = 2^{3} \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Suppose there is such $G$. Then checking $n_{5}(G) = 6$ and considering action on right cosets of $N_{G}(P)$ with $P \in \text{Syl}_{5}(G)$, we can inject this group $G \leqslant S_{6}$.

How do we show $G \leqslant A_{6}$? And in general, what assumptions are used when a subgroup of $S_{n}$ is in $A_{n}$? For the second question any examples will be appreciated whether they are trivial or not.

Comment: What is $n_5(G)$ ?

Comment: $n_{5}(G) := |\text{Syl}_{5}(G)|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map $$G\hookrightarrow S_6\rightarrow \lbrace -1,+1\rbrace$$ where the last morphism is the signature morphism. By simplicity of $G$, this has to be trivial, so the image of $G$ under te embedding in $S_6$ lies in the kernel of the signature, which happens to be the alternating group $A_6$.

It's the same idea as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173470/simple-group-of-order-660-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-a-12/173481#173481).

Answer (score 3):

Well if $G\not\subset A_6,$ then $G\cap A_6$ would be a proper normal subgroup.

Comment: Could the intersection be just the identity?

Comment: @gnometorule It can't; if it were then any non-identity $x \in G$ would satisfy $x^2=1$, so the order $G$ would be a power of 2.

Comment: Not a power of 2. Order exactly 2 (or 1).